# How to install httpd on RedHat Server? What Yum repository?

Tags: apache, http, repository, redhat, yum

I am pretty new with this kind of server so please excuse my ignorance.

I asked my company for a Linux Server for hosting a web application and they gave me this system:
*Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)*
so the first thing I did was trying to install Apache HTTP, which package is called httpd in yum repositories.

Following a tutorial I did:

```
sudo yum list httpd
```

Which started returning a series of time out messages coming from a mirror related to my company (Are they hosting rhel repositories? Is this a common practice?)

Anyway I started disabling this mirrors at which point the command

```
sudo yum list httpd
```

returned just:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Repository rhel-7-server-rpms is listed more than once in the configuration
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

I tried adding back some repo without any basic knowledge of the technology so I'll just post the result of this command:

```
sudo yum repolist enabled

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Repository rhel-7-server-rpms is listed more than once in the configuration
repo id                                                 repo name                                                        status
epel/x86_64                                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                   13,457
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64              Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Optional (RPMs)              19,380
vmware-tools                                            VMware Tools                                                          1
repolist: 32,838
```

What should I do? How do I know which repo to add and/or enable to install this common package?

Comment: `httpd` is provided by the [base](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/) repo. It looks like thats missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpd2.4 for RHEL is packaged as a Software Collection, so you have to enable some repos first. See these docs:

[Release notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/2/html/2.4_release_notes/chap-rhscl)
[Installation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/2/html/2.0_release_notes/chap-installation)

Once you "scl enable" the proper repos, then you'll "yum install httpd24"

If you want a shortcut for setup, use step 1 only on this [Python Hello World page](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world#fndtn-python), then yum install.